# Upgrade video card on Dell Inspiron e1505/6400 laptop?

Tags: laptop, upgrade, dell-inspiron

I have a [Dell Inspiron 6400/E1505](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/SYSTEMS/ins6400/en/sm/index.htm) laptop. I ordered it several years ago. It uses an onboard video chip.

Is it possible to upgrade the video card on this laptop using an expansion card?

I've searched dell.com and asked Dell support. Dell support was vague and unwilling to provide an answer. It's difficult to find an answer to this question, because Dell sometimes calls this model an 'e1505', and sometimes calls this model a '6400'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are four options for graphics in the dell inspiron 6400/e1505. you can get an intel 970 i think, and if you get that there is no way to upgrade. or there are three graphics cards that can be bought for the laptop and can come with it.
there is the ati x1300 which is stock, the ati x1400 which is slightly better, then you can get the nvidia geforce GO 7300 which is the best available grpahics card for this laptop. The nvidia option comes for about 50 dollars.
My specs:
dell inspiron 6400
windows xp service pack 3
1 gig of ram
1.8ghz intel centrino processor
ati x1300 graphics.
Benchmark: minecraft lowest settings 50 fps.
by the way, its probably better just to go buy a better computer as dell integrated graphics now have more memory than any of these cards.
Seriously, though. I saved up 750 dollars and built a new top of the line desktop, and you can build a really nice amd apu based gaming computer for around 400. cheap as crap.

---

##

Answer (score 1):

You cannot normally upgrade the graphics card on a laptop as most don't have card slots of any type. I have seen a few oversize docking stations that include a card slot. I had one for a Dell Precisions series that had a PCI slot, but I never tried a graphics card in. But the docking stations are not really portable and I certainly did not carry it with me. I only used at my desk.

You might get a small improvement by upgrading your graphics drivers. other then that, your only choice maybe to get a new PC.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can upgrade it.  The e15050 and 6400 are pretty much the same but 6400 was a business model.  The best video card it will support is an ATI X1400.

Comment: Do you have a link to verify this? I didn't see any slots last time I opened the case, but I could be wrong.